# Using completion handlers inside while loop

Tags: swift, while-loop, alamofire, completionhandler

How to use completion handlers/dispatchqueue within while loops?

I have this method called `getHub()` which is a completion handler as I would like code to be executed after it has finished with the relevant values. I call this when a user presses a button:

```
SetupAPI().getHub(completion: { response, error in
     print("testing")
     print(response)
     print(error)
})
```

(The code above is where all of the code below should end at)

It calls my API and if the API returns an error/a value that I wasn't expecting, or if Almofire couldn't do the request for some reason, then it adds one onto the `tries` variable. The max amount of tries allowed is 3 given by the `maxTries` variable. If the `tries` variable is equal to the `maxTries` variable, then a bool `timeout` is set to `true`. If the `tries` variable is below the `maxTries` variable then the code waits `timeoutInSeconds` - which is 10 seconds - amount of time before exiting the while loop, which should run the code once more.

Similarly, If the right value is returned from fetching the data from my API then a bool `found` is set to `true`.

If either of these variables are true, then the while loop breaks. And an error is sent back to the completion handler for the code above (which then allows me to tell the user that something has gone wrong).

However, when I run it, the completion handler above is not finished, and the code just runs through the while loop and called function over and over again as my console fills with `starting` and `fetching` via my two print statements for debugging in below code. What's the problem, can I use a DispatchQueue/ completion handlers in this situation?

Function that gets called via above code:

```
func getHub(completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    var tries = 0
    let maxTries = 3
    let timeoutInSeconds = 10.0
    var found = false
    var timeout = false
    
    while !found || !timeout{
        print("starting")
        getHubCallAPI(completion: {status, error in
            if(error == nil){
                print(status)
                if (status == "No documents found"){
                    if(tries >= maxTries){
                        print("Tired too many times")
                        timeout = true
                        return completion(false, nil)
                    }
                    tries += 1
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeoutInSeconds){
                        return
                    }
                }else{
                    found = true
                    print("Hub found")
                    return completion(true, nil)
                }
            }else{
                print("error")
                return completion(false, error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Function that calls the API and returns it back to the function above ^^:

```
func getHubCallAPI(completion: @escaping (String, Error?) -> Void) {
    print("fetching")
    AF.request("https://discovery.ellisn.com", encoding: URLEncoding.default).response { response in
        print("Request: \(response.request)")
        print("Response: \(response.response)")
        print("Error: \(response.error)")
        if(response.error != nil){
            return completion("", response.error)
        }
        if let data = response.data, let status = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            return completion(status, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Any questions, or more clarification needed, then just ask. Thanks.

Comment: This is because your while loop runs on the main thread and will not wait for the getHubCallAPI (on another thread) to finish. You can call getHubCallAPI once and then call it recursively in the completion (until `found` or `timeout`).

Comment: @pawello2222 could you add your comment as an answer with code for myself and others to improve this question?

Comment: I added it as an answer. Feel free to correct me if I misunderstood your desired behaviour in the completion handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
func getHub(triesLeft: Int = 3, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    let timeoutInSeconds = 1.0

    print("starting")
    getHubCallAPI(completion: { status, error in
        if error == nil {
            print(status)
            if status != "No documents found" {
                print("Hub found")
                return completion(true, nil)
            }
        } else {
            print("error")
            return completion(false, error) // comment out if the loop should continue on error
        }
        if triesLeft <= 1 {
            print("Tried too many times")
            return completion(false, nil)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeoutInSeconds) {
            getHub(triesLeft: triesLeft - 1, completion: completion)
        }
    })
}
```

And just call it once like this:

```
getHub(triesLeft: 2, completion: { ... })
```

---

Note that unless you need it for some other reason, there is no need to return `(Bool, Error?)`. And the second parameter is always `nil` - you may want to propagate your error. You could in theory return `(String?, Error?)`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense now. Thank you for that, didn't think that it would be too separate threads.

Comment: @Nathan Usually when you see a word *completion* it indicates the function might be asynchronous (ie. run in the background).